# How to update an specific value in a Many to Many Relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables to handle the parents of an animal, in the pivot table I store the "id" of the child animal and the parent animal, in the other table I have a gender field to define whether it is the mother or the father.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

The problem is when updating this data, because is a many-to-many relationship I can only call all the parents, what I want is to update one by one comparing them with the gender.

In my "Ganado" model I have two functions defined to see the parents and to assign them:

```
public function padres()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ganado', 'hijos_padres', 'id_hijo',  'id_padre');
}

public function hijos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ganado', 'hijos_padres', 'id_padre', 'id_hijo');
}

public function asignarPadre($id_padre)
{
    $this->padres()->sync($id_padre, false);
}
```

In my controller I update the data like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $bovino = Ganado::findOrFail($id);

    $bovino->codigo_ganado = $request->get('codbovino');
    $bovino->nombre = request('nombre');
    $bovino->lote_ingreso = request('loteIn');
    $bovino->lote_actual = request('loteAct');
    $bovino->ganaderia = $request->get('ganaderia');
    $bovino->etapa = $request->get('etapa');
    $bovino->genero = $request->get('genero');
    $bovino->id_raza = $request->get('raza');
    $bovino->fecha = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->input('fechaNac'))->format('Y-m-d');

    if ($request->hasFile('imagen')) {
        $file = $request->imagen;
        $file->move(public_path() . '/images', $file->getClientOriginalName());
        $bovino->imagen = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    //This is how im trying to update a parent
    $id_padre = $bovino->padres()->pluck('id_padre')->toArray();
    $bovino->padres()->updateExistingPivot($id_padre, ['id_padre' => $request->get('padre')]);        

    $bovino->update();

    return redirect('/ganado/engorde');
}
```

And finally, I want to update both parents (father and mother), and I have 2 "select" where I show all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code to update one by one comparing them with the gender:

```
// $padres is a collection containing both parents 
$padres = $bovino->padres()->get();
// foreach loop to differentiate the mother and father
foreach($padres as $padre){
    if($padre->genero === GENERO_MUJER){
        //mother
    } else {
        //father
    }
}
```